# Displaying an image from A Db

Tags: php, sql

I have a search bar(YES I know its vunerable to SQL injection) BUT  I need to know how to display the image:
here is the DB:
ItemID Name       Price Description Image
1      star wars   9.99 "blah blah" starwars.jpg

This code display the name and the description but wont display the image

```
                 <?php

if(!isset($_POST['search']))
{
    header("Location:index.php");

}

$search_sql="SELECT * FROM php_item WHERE Name LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%' OR Description LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'";
$search_query = mysql_query($search_sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($search_query)!=0)
{

$search_rs= mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query);
}


?>


          </p>
          <p>&nbsp; Search Results: <a href="search.php" title="search again">Search Again</a></p>
          <?php

          if(mysql_num_rows($search_query) != 0){
              do{ ?>

              <p>
              <?php echo $search_rs['Name']; 
              echo $search_rs['Description'];
               ?> 

             <?php }while($search_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query));





          } else {
            echo "No Results Found";  
          }





          ?>
```

Comment: Well it won't display the image, cause there is no code for the image, where do you think it should display the image?

Comment: exactly.. thats what I was thinking.. its says its stored as a varchar as well:S this was given to me by a uni tutor.. wlel i want the image to display under the description

Comment: The Varchar is for the image name, I think that is what you need to use where i wrote $search_rs['Img']'.jpg/>

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work

```
if(mysql_num_rows($search_query) != 0){
          do{ ?>

          <p>
          <?php echo $search_rs['Name']; 
          echo $search_rs['Description'];
          echo "<img src='$search_rs['Img']'
                 .jpg/>";
           ?> 

         <?php }while($search_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query));





      } else {
        echo "No Results Found";  
      }
```